# Zend_Form_Element_File (no decorator found error)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am creating a form with an upload element. I have created the file element with the code below

```
 $image = new Zend_Form_Element_File('image');
 $image->setAttrib('title','Listing Image:')
       ->addDecorator('File')
       ->addValidator('Size', false, 204800)
       ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif');

  $this->addElement($image);
```

Which as far as I can tell works fine. It tries to add a file element to the page. I get an error which says " Warning: No file decorator found... unable to render file element in..."

As you can see I have set the decorator for the element to be the File decorator so I am unsure why I am getting this error?

It is worth noting I have removed all default decorators except for viewHelper and PrepareElements and I am using a view partial as the viewHelper to display the output. Just incase this is required I have also included that below.

```
<form method="<?php echo $this->element->getMethod(); ?>" action="<?php echo $this->element->getAction(); ?>">
<div class="boxmiddle-Holder">
    <div class="boxmiddle-content">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" class="dataTable">
            <?php foreach($this->element->getElements() as $element): ?>

                        <!-- if not a button then display label -->
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="<?php echo $element->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $element->getAttrib('title'); ?></label></td>

                        <td class="normal"><?php echo $element; ?></td>
                        <?php if($element->getMessages()) {
                            foreach($element->getMessages() as $message) { ?>
                                <td> <?php echo "<p class='elementError'>".$message."</p>"; ?></td>
                         <?php    }
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd double check to make sure the File decorator isn't being cleared or reset later, that error indicates that your form's file element does not have a `Zend_Form_Decorator_File` decorator attached to it.

Look in `Zend/Form/Element/File.php` around line 859 for the function that throws this error.  I suspect somehow the File decorator is being removed from the element.  It could be that it has no decorators or is just lacking the `File` decorator.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I checked all the code and I can't seem to find anywhere that removes the decorator. The only thing I can think of is that my view partial used to render the form I included above maybe doesn't output the decorator even though it has one set?

Comment: In your loop, try a `var_dump($element->getDecorators());` on the File element and see what the result is.  I'm curious to see what it has registered.  When creating the element, you may want to change `->addDecorator('File')` to `->setDecorator(array('File'))` instead so that all existing ones are removed and replaced with the File decorator.

Comment: I sorted it. At the bottom of the form I was setting the form element decorators. When using this it seemed to override the decorators I set for individual elements. What i've done to fix it is remove the general settings at the bottom of the form and assigned each element the decorators It requires.